# Tomcat Re-write rule with AngularJS gives 404 on browser refresh

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, redirect, url-rewriting, routes

I am using `Tomcat 8.5.11` running a REST end-point and AngularJS.
The REST end-point has `/api` as the url, however, AngularJS as multiple urls (obviously).
When I copy and paste or on browser refresh the url (e.g. `localhost/user`). I get a `404` response.

What I want to do is tell Tomcat to let the directory request pass through.

When I use the following rule in the `rewrite.config` file as mentioned in the [docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html).-

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
```

I get the exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException The resource path [null] is not valid`

When I use the following rule, all works fine -

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(user)*$
```

I want a generic solution where I do not have to add all AngularJS routes in the `rewrite.config` file but something generic.

The complete entry in the rewrite.config file is as follows -

```
# UI Folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(fonts|icons|img)\/*$ [OR]
# UI files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/*\.(css|js)$ [OR]
# UI routes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR] <-- Fails
# REST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(api)\/*$

RewriteRule (.*) /index.html [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm having the same problem